# Some problems with Javascript functions and this argument

Tags: javascript, function, this, dom-events, colorbox

I am using colorbox to my popups and...

This works fine.

```
$(".show_popup").colorbox({inline:true, width:"800px", onOpen: function() {
   type = $(this).attr('type);
   ....
}
```

But I want use my inner function many times so I want make it a module function.

});

```
(function ($,a) {
 var p = {
   showPopup: function (popup_type) { 
    ...
   },

   bindEvents: function () {
       $(".show_popup").colorbox({inline:true, width:"800px", onOpen: p.showPopup($(this).attr('type')) }); 
   }
...
}
a.Popups = p;
})(jQuery);
```

But this don't work - it is problem with `$(this)` - and function execute only once after page loading.

```
(function ($,a) {
  var p = {
   showPopup: function (popup_type) { 
    ...
   },

   bindEvents: function () {
       $(".show_popup").colorbox({inline:true, width:"800px", onOpen: p.showPopup }); 
   }
...
}
a.Popups = p;

})(jQuery);
```

And this don't work of course too, but execute many times. So can you help me know what is matter?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're doing or what your issue is. Please make a sample on a service like jsbin.com and include only what is relevant to your issue. That makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: bfavaretto, I have made my code more complete. Sorry for stupid copy - paste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `onOpen: p.showPopup($(this).attr('type))` is that it will run the p.showPopup-function at the moment that you bind it to onOpen. What you want is that it runs at the moment the onOpen-event is triggered. Use

```
onOpen: function() { p.showPopup($(this).attr('type')); }
```

instead

(edit) assuming that p.showPopup is defined, I can't see it in your code.